# How include files in changeLog by mask

Tags: liquibase

We have pretty standard change-log.xml:

```html
<databaseChangeLog …>
  <include file="changes/change1.xml"/>
  <include file="changes/change2.xml"/>
    …
  <include file="changes/changeN.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The problem is N is constantly climbing and is already around 200, considering that we're only using liquibase for several months, I'm concerned that the file will soon become too big to work with comfortably. Also I don't like that several developers can change this file concurrently, yes Git takes care of conflicts, but still I don't like it. Another problem is that developers have to remember updating the file each time they write a new change file.

Is there a way to include files by mask? Something along the lines of

```html
<databaseChangeLog …>
  <include file="changes/*.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify the path in includeAll tag, we use it like this:

```
<includeAll path="config/liquibase/changelog/" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

In your case it may be

```
<includeAll path="changes/"/>
```